# Issue with Promise bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, nodes, bluebird

So I'm using Promise.mapSeries from bluebird in nodeJS.

I'm confronted to a weird situation, I don't understand what is going wrong.

```js
remove: function(req, res) {
  var ru;
  return Rules.findOne({
    ru_id: parseInt(req.query.ru_id)
  }).populate('producturl').then(function(_ru) {
    console.log('1');
    ru = _ru;
  }).then(function() {
    return Promise.mapSeries(ru.producturl, function(prUrl) {
      console.log('2');
      return Products.findOne(prUrl.p_id).populate('producturl').populate('et_id').then(function(pr) {
        console.log('3');
        if (pr.producturl.length > 1) {
          return EntityService.removeDirectory(ru.producturl[0].url).then(function() {
            return;
          })
        } else {
          console.log('4');
          var newUrl = root + '/uploads/Segmentation/' + pr.et_id.name + '/notAffected/' + pr.name;
          newUrl = stringConversion.removeDiacritics(newUrl);
          var ur_id = pr.producturl[0].ur_id;
          return ProductURL.update({
            ur_id: ur_id
          }, {
            url: newUrl
          }).then(function() {
            console.log('5');
            return EntityService.moveDirectory(prUrl.url, newUrl).then(function() {
              console.log('6');
              return;
            }, function(err) {
              return res.negotiate(err);
            })
          }, function(err) {
            return res.negotiate(err);
          });
        }
      }, function(err) {
        return res.negotiate(err);
      });
    }).then(function() {
      console.log('7');
      return Rules.destroy({
        ru_id: parseInt(req.query.ru_id)
      }).then(function() {
        console.log('8');
        res.ok();
      }, function(err) {
        return res.negotiate(err);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

The console.log print out :
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

It doesn't go to the console.log('8') and instead after a long time start again and print 1 2 3 ...

Comment: In general, your issue is that rather than one continuous promise chain, you are creating multiple independent promise chains and the main reason is that you are running async operations inside of `.then()` handlers that are not directly chained to a promise you return from the `.then()` handler.  When you create multiple independent promise chains that are not linked together, they run independently and you lose control of the order between chains.

Comment: What database is it?  Does it have a promise interface instead of the traditional callbacks.  You will need to use promises for your async operations such as `.exec()`, not callbacks.  It's very difficult to make things work if you mix promises and traditional callbacks.  It's very easy to make things work if you use all promises and return all promises from within `.then()` handlers.

Comment: For example, your `Promise.mapSeries()` call creates a new independent promise chain that is not linked to anything else.  There are a whole bunch of promise anti-patterns in this code example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using sailsJS which use Waterline and Mysql for the DB. You were right, I just notice that exec used callback. I will update it and remove the first promise which is useless. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Both `rimraf` and `mv` don't seem to be properly promisified.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated my snippet with the new results. How to you chain the Promise.mapSeries to the precedent promise ? I though it was already the case because it's contained in the then of Rules.findOne.

Comment: This is indeed weird. Logging `5` but not `6` and the following can easily explained by `Rules.destroy` failing (try adding another logging statement to the rejection handler), but logging `1` again (which is outside of the `Promise.mapSeries` loop) suggests you are calling `remove` twice.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your comments. Removing Rules.destroy and rimraf/ mv still generate the same issue. They must be an issue with a promise not ending at some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try flattening your promise callbacks a bit:

```
remove: function(req, res) {
  console.log('0');
  return Rules.findOne({
    ru_id: parseInt(req.query.ru_id)
  }).populate('producturl').then(function(ru) {
    console.log('1');
    return Promise.mapSeries(ru.producturl, function(prUrl) {
      console.log('2');
      return Products.findOne(prUrl.p_id).populate('producturl').populate('et_id').then(function(pr) {
        console.log('3');
        if (pr.producturl.length > 1) {
          return EntityService.removeDirectory(ru.producturl[0].url);
        } else {
          console.log('4');
          var newUrl = root + '/uploads/Segmentation/' + pr.et_id.name + '/notAffected/' + pr.name;
          newUrl = stringConversion.removeDiacritics(newUrl);
          var ur_id = pr.producturl[0].ur_id;
          return ProductURL.update({
            ur_id: ur_id
          }, {
            url: newUrl
          }).then(function() {
            console.log('5');
            return EntityService.moveDirectory(prUrl.url, newUrl);
          }).then(function() {
            console.log('6');
            return;
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }).then(function() {
    console.log('7');
    return Rules.destroy({
      ru_id: parseInt(req.query.ru_id)
    });
  }).then(function() {
    console.log('8');
    res.ok();
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('something went wrong');
    res.negotiate(err);
  });
}
```

While we cannot grasp what went wrong in your original code, and especially not understand how `1` was logged multiple times, I'd wager that some of your premature error handlers threw off your control flow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could my error handlers could threw off my control flow ?

Comment: Because they are *handling* the errors and letting your program continue instead of bubbling the exceptions to the end. Can you please try my version and see what it logs?

Comment: -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. After a while (2-3min) I got -> 0 1  and then I got "something went wrong" and then it breaks which is normal because it can't find the ru_id (deleted the first time). So it weirdly loop in circles... I have a doubt with promise.mapSeries, I think it never complete my promise.

Comment: If you are getting `0` again, that means that you are calling the `remove` method again (like another client request). This is not the fault of promises but must be found elsewhere in your code (or even in the client retry behaviour). If you are not getting to `8` it means that `Rules.destroy` hangs, you should investigate there.

Comment: I Finally found what was wrong !! I had define in my Rules model an afterDestroy function and forgot to call the callback function at the end of it. So the problem came from Rules.destroy ... By the way, in your version of my code you're handling the error at the end. If an error occurred inside my Promise.mapSeries, is the error will be thrown ?

Comment: Yes, any rejections will bubble outside and will be caught in the error handler at the end. Just like an exception in synchronous code - you'd probably only use one big `try` that encloses everything there as well.